# Combobox selection warns "This implementation does not support subelements"

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, touchscreen

On my touchscreen computer, I get a warning when I use a simple Qt combobox (in PySide):

```
class MyComBox(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        comboxText=["Hi", "Bye", "Give me a warning"]
        self.comBox=QtGui.QComboBox(self) 
        self.comBox.addItems(comboxText)
        self.comBox.move(20,40)  
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 100)
        self.show()
```

When I create an instance of the GUI, the GUI looks as I expect, but when I press on the dropdown menu, I get the following warning in my shell:

```
QAccessibleWidget::rect: This implementation does not support subelements! (ID 1 unknown for QWidget)
```

While it is somewhat innocuous, I'd like to make this go away as it is distracting when it pops up every time someone clicks on a combobox. Google has not yielded much on the topic, except the following related discussion:
http://www.daz3d.com/forums/viewthread/6773/

I am on Windows 7 and Python 2.7, running under Anaconda. Note I am only getting this error on my Dell touchscreen laptop, but not my work desktops (neither of which are touch screen). All are Windows 7, but the touchscreen laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15z "downgraded" from Windows 8.

Because of the lack of people clamoring with me about this problem, it is clear this seems fairly localized to me. Hence I have submitted this as a bug report at the Qt Project site (https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/PYSIDE-242). I will update here if I hear anything back.

Comment: Your code looks quite like ordinary, perfectly fine PySide using code. Also in CPython you don't get any warning. It's more likely a problem with iPython.

Comment: Just tried on my touch-screen computer and even from windows command line when I run code I get same error. So it isn't iPython's fault...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread http://niftools.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=2147 indicates that it is a problem with Qt accessibility support on some touch/tablets. Can you try disabling the `Tablet PC Components` (or, in Vista, `Tablet PC Optional Components`) from `Control Panel -> Program Features -> Turn Windows Features On or Off`, as mentioned in the last post there and check if it works.

Also, if you just want to suppress the the warning, since it is innocuous, you can install your own message handler using `QtCore.qInstallMsgHandler()`

And, this is more likely a Qt issue than a PySide one.

Comment: it worked, thank you for solving this mystery (or at least pointing more helpfully toward its likely source). Strangely my touchscreen features seem to be working just fine even with that feature disabled, so I'm not sure what exactly is disabled, and couldn't find a good description online of what `Tablet PC Components` does (I just found this minimal nondescriptive description: http://winsupersite.com/article/faqtip/windows-7-tip-of-the-week-remove-the-windows-features-you-dont-need). Anyone have a good description?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows8. Stopping the service TabletInputService seemed to fix it for me